# How to write mysql query in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, mysql-error-1055

I am new to laravel and i want to write mysql query in laravel 5.4.
query is like :

note: avoid column names..

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * 
      FROM messages 
      WHERE (from_id=1 OR to_id=1) 
ORDER BY created DESC) as m 
GROUP BY `from_id`
```

I tried but gives error.

```
$messages = DB::table('messagetbl')
                ->select('*')
                ->Where(function($query) use ($userid){
                    $query->distinct()
                    ->where('senderid',$userid)
                    ->orWhere('receiverid',$userid)
                    ->orderBy('datetime','desc');
                 })
                ->groupBy('senderid')
                ->get();
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'db.messagetbl.id' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `messagetbl` where
>   (`senderid` = 8 or `receiverid` = 8) group by `senderid`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the full stack trace of the error and explain more clearly the problem. Refer to [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this:

```
  DB::table('messages')
        ->select('*') 
        ->where('form_id', '=', 1)
        ->orWhere('to_id', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy('created', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('form_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Comment: error:   Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.messagetbl.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: reset sql_mode in config/app.php :      'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        ...
        'init' => ["SET sql_mode = ''"],
    ],

Comment: can u pls explain what error is it? it is related to some primary key issue or what.

Comment: This its  a warning that your query is ambiguous. You want to select all from messages then the form_id column is used for grouping. The solution here is SELECT form_id , or to apply an aggregate operator like MIN() to it.

Comment: I get all data not group by :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147564/discussion-between-l-kelmendi-and-v-dev).